# Chance making by credits on the slot machine

Tags: javascript, html, slot

**Hello, I made a slot machine with javascript, but the player's chances need to increase according to her credit, I couldn't find how to do it?
In other words, the more credits the player has, the more I want her chances to increase.
Also, my English is not very good, please excuse me.

```js
var imageArray = [
  "https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/previews/000/379/291/non_2x/dollar-vector-icon.jpg",
  "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/casino/256/Cherries-256.png",
  "https://st3.depositphotos.com/8804418/15929/v/450/depositphotos_159290092-stock-illustration-slot-machine-seven-icon-color.jpg"
];

var randomNum1;
var randomNum2;
var randomNum3;


function generateRandomPicture() {
  randomNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length);
  randomNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length);
  randomNum3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * imageArray.length);
  document.getElementById("kiraz1").setAttribute("src", imageArray[randomNum1]);
  document.getElementById("kiraz2").setAttribute("src", imageArray[randomNum2]);
  document.getElementById("kiraz3").setAttribute("src", imageArray[randomNum3]);
}
var item1 = document.getElementById("item1");
var item2 = document.getElementById("item2");
var item3 = document.getElementById("item3");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.onclick = function() {
  generateRandomPicture();
  if (randomNum1 === randomNum2 && randomNum1 === randomNum3) {
    Ses();
    arttır();
  } else {
    Error();
    azaltma();
  }

}

function Ses() {
  ses.play();
}

function Error() {
  error.play();
}

function azaltma() {
  var deger = parseInt(document.getElementById('kk').value);
  document.getElementById('kk').value = deger - 1;
  if (deger === 0) {
    alert("limitiniz dolmuştur.");
  } else {
    return;
  }
}

function arttır() {
  var deger1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('kk').value);
  document.getElementById('kk').value = deger1 + 1;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="center">Slot Makinesi</h1>
<table class="centera">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="kiraz.png" alt="" id="kiraz1" style="max-width: 130px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="kiraz.png" alt="" id="kiraz2" style="max-width: 130px;">
      </td>
      <td>
        <img src="kiraz.png" alt="" id="kiraz3" style="max-width: 130px;">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div class="lever">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn">Bas</button>
</div>
<input type="number" name="Kalan_Kullanım" id="kk" class="kk" onclick="azaltma()" value="10" min="0">
<audio src="html_guessing-game_boing.mp3" id="ses">
        </audio>
<audio src="error-sesi-efekti-kisa.mp3" id="error"></audio>

<script src="slot.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think I would approach it (with the information you've provided). Let's say the player get's no chance increase if credits are < 5. A smaller chance increase if credits are >= 5 and < 10. And a larger increase if credits is > 10.

In your generateRandomPicture function, if the player has put in lets say 5 credits. I would generate randomNumberOne (let's say it picks 0), and then for randomNumberTwo, I would generate a random number between only two numbers (with one of them being one of the numbers selected in randomNumberOne. So in this example so far, randomNumberTwo would be selected between [0,1] or [0,2] instead of [0,1,2].

Then if the player puts in let's say 15 credits, you would do the same process, except reduce the number of possibilities for randomNumberThree as well.

Example (3 credits):

RandomNumberOne = choose random number from [0,1,2]
RandomNumberTwo = choose random number from [0,1,2]
RandomNumberThree = choose random number from [0,1,2]

Example (7 credits):

RandomNumberOne = choose random number from [0,1,2] (it selects 2)
RandomNumberTwo = choose random number from [0,2] or [1,2]
RandomNumberThree = choose random number from [0,1,2]

Example (15 credits):

RandomNumberOne = choose random number from [0,1,2] (it selects 1)
RandomNumberTwo = choose random number from [0,1] or [1,2]
RandomNumberThree = choose random number from [0,1] or [1,2]

Comment: Got it right I'm opening an array with random images. And I'll call these images according to the credits